# Add richtext field to a documnet library - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library

I have  requirement to use a rich text field in a document library.
Is it possible to add a new filed with rich text field to a document library?
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try using PowerShell or Designer workaround given here: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/rich-text-column-in-sharepoint-document-library.html. Let me know if it works for you!

Comment: Thanks Ganesh.
Can I still open SharePoint Online with SharePoint Designer?
Will give it a shot

Comment: Yes, you can open.

Comment: Is it working for you?

Comment: I haven't installed SP Designer yet but i will give it a try

Comment: Any update here? If you don't have SP designer, can you try PowerShell way?

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I can't open SP Designer with SharePoint Online sites. Not sure how it worked for you. Do you have a script for the powershell perhaps?